# Generate All Possible Combinations of a Nested List

Tags: python

Say I had  the following nested list in Python:

```
lst = [[0, 1, 2],
       [3],
       [4, 5]]
```

I want to create a list of all the possible number combinations of length `lst` where each list within `lst` is sampled only once for each combination. So the output for this example would be:

```
[[0,3,4], [0,3,5], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [2,3,4], [2,3,5]]
```

I could do:

```
[[x0,x1,x2] for x0 in lst[0] for x1 in lst[1] for x2 in lst[2]]
```

which returns the correct answer here, but in my case I don't know how many lists are nested in `lst` so how would I do this efficiently if the number of lists is variable?

Comment: @blackbrandt That is not the same question as this; this one is just a simple case for `itertools.product`.

Comment: @kaya3, you are correct, that's just what I need thanks!

Comment: confirmed that `list(itertools.product(*lst))` seems to work